# Why magento not provide facility of add product for a store view

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, multistore, programming

I am working on multi store functionality and stuck in a problem for managing products.
My requirement is just around for store views products that's why sending this post.
I just want to know, why magento not implement functionality at the time of add product for choose store view also.

Answer (score 1):

This is a philosophical question. I doubt you will get an answer to "why is it like this". The answer is "just because".
But to solve your problem, you can associate a product to a website, set it's visibility to "not individually" an then edit the product on a specific store view and set the visibility to "Catalog & search" for that store view only.